# GCP Logging Sink not exporting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Problem:
I have created a BigQuery sink within GCP Logging, but no data gets exported into the BigQuery table.

I can see the created sink within the "Logs Router" tab within GCP Logging.
In addition I can see the corresponding dataset and table within BigQuery.
I have also checked if the corresponding Service Account has sufficient permissions. It has "BigQuery Data Editor" permissions.

I have already tried to delete the sink and create a new one. This did not help.
In addition I have compared my sink settings with other working sinks from other GCP projects, but it is the same setup.

Last but not least I had a look into GCP Monitoring.
There I can see the event "LoggingSinkConfigErrorV2".
But I do not know the meaning of this event and also my Google search was not successful.

[image: Event error]

EDIT 01.09.2020:

[image: GCP Logging]

EDIT 01.09.2020:

[image: GCP Advanced Logging]

Comment: you can check corresponding error in Stackdriver, just go to advanced tab and search for sink name. Later could you share the error?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot. There is no error message. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I'm not sure all logs are present under "Logging export sink" tab. Can you go to advanced view and search for name of the sink?

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting described in [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#troubleshooting)

Comment: @lukaszberwid I hope by "advanced view" you mean the new preview mode. I looked into "BigQuery", "BigQuery Dataset", "BigQuery Project", "Logging export sink" and "Error" but there was not any infomation regarding the event "LoggingSinkConfigErrorV2".

Comment: I also had a look into public docs. The setup seems to be right.

Comment: @JShinigami Try raise a GCP support case , if you have the option to do it.

Comment: I would like to point a section of this document shared on a previous comment here: 
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#errors_exporting_to_bigquery

Check for ORGanization policies errors to start. On the section shared, you can search for: "Logs cannot be streamed to dataset [YOUR_DATASET] because that operation is prohibited by an organization policy." 

Later check if the billing of the project that has the BQ is OK.

Comment: I also wanted to share this about the advanced GCP Logging queries:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#getting-started

You can use an advanced filter like severity>=ERROR

Comment: @CarloC. Thank you for the hint regarding billing. This was the cause. There was no billng for the project :)

Comment: I'm really glad JShinigami :), please be so kind as to accept (green tick) the new answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the Billing of the GCP project that contains the BigQuery is OK.

Comment: Yes, if a billing account is not configured, exporting to BigQuery will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you created sink right.

**Important** thing to note is --> Once you create sink, any **NEW** logs after creating sink will be exported to GCP and old logs will **NOT** export.

So once you create sink ,make sure you do some activity to get new logs generated.

Comment: @JShinigami In case you used any filter , can you check the filter works by using same filter in stackdriver logging.

Comment: Yes the filter should work. The filter is: resource.type="app_script_function"

Comment: @JShinigami can you post  a screenshot of logging screen ,where you search  resource.type="app_script_function" and some logs show up. Also put screenshot of your sink..